# C# to unzip all nested zips in a directory while preserving file structure

Tags: c#, unzip

I am trying to unzip all zips within a directory, which sometimes contain nested zips multiple layers down. I want to also preserve the original zip nesting structure in the extracted version. I am able to do what I want with one layer of zips, but not for nested zips or zips inside subfolders.

For example I want to turn everything in the starting folder like this:

```
[Starting Folder]
-Zip1.zip
--NestedZip1.zip
---text1.txt
--NestedZip2.zip
---text2.txt
-Zip2.zip
--[Subfolder1]
---Zip3.zip
----text3.txt
---Zip4.zip
----text4.txt
```

And extract everything to a folder in that same starting directory:

```
[Starting Folder]
[Extracted Folder]
-Zip1 (folder)
--NestedZip1 (folder)
---text1.txt
--NestedZip2 (folder)
---text2.txt
-Zip2 (folder)
--[Subfolder1]
---Zip3 (folder)
----text3.txt
---Zip4 (folder)
----text4.txt
```

Right now I am using this to unzip all the files in MyGlobals.finalPathForWork (which is the starting directory) and it works but only unzips one layer of zips. I need it to run again somehow in case there were zips in that first layer of zips.

```
        public static void MyMethod3()
    {
        string startPath = MyGlobals.finalPathForWork;
        string extractPath = MyGlobals.finalPathForWork + @"\\Extracted\";
        Directory.GetFiles(startPath, "*.zip", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList()
            .ForEach(zipFilePath =>
            {
                var extractPathForCurrentZip = Path.Combine(extractPath, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(zipFilePath));
                if (!Directory.Exists(extractPathForCurrentZip))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(extractPathForCurrentZip);
                }
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFilePath, extractPathForCurrentZip);
            });
    }
```

I've tried applying/combining pieces of this: [How to unzip multi layered zip files in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61108954/how-to-unzip-multi-layered-zip-files-in-c-sharp)

```
public static void ExtractFile(string baseZipPath, string extractPath)
{
        if (!Directory.Exists(extractPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(extractPath);

        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(baseZipPath, extractPath);
        string[] nestedZipDirectories = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(extractPath, "*.zip");
        foreach (var nestedZipDirectory in nestedZipDirectories)
        {
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(nestedZipDirectory, extractPath);
        }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExtractFile(@"c:\myfolder\grandfather.zip", @"c:\myfolder2");
}
```

Is there another way to loop the searching/unzipping process down through all subfolders and nested zip files? Or should that other solution above work and I'm must just be incorporating it incorrectly?

Answer (score 5):

This is a classic use-case for recursion.
Note the comments in the code:

```cs
public static void ExtractFile(string zipFilePath, string extractPath)
{
    // If directory already exist, CreateDirectory does nothing
    Directory.CreateDirectory(extractPath); 

    // Extract current zip file
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFilePath, extractPath);

    // Enumerate nested zip files
    var nestedZipFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(extractPath, "*.zip");

    // iterate the enumerator
    foreach (var nestedZipFile in nestedZipFiles)
    {    
        // Get the nested zip full path + it's file name without the ".zip" extension
        // I.E this "C:\users\YourUserName\Documents\SomeZipFile.Zip" - turns to this: "C:\users\YourUserName\Documents\SomeZipFile".
        var nestedZipExtractPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(nestedZipFile), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(nestedZipFile));

        // extract recursively
        ExtractFile(nestedZipFile, nestedZipExtractPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I can tell what is happening thanks to your comments, but how do I pass it the directory I want to run this in? Right now, the only thing I'm passing to any of my methods is "MyGlobals.finalPathForWork" - which is the directory I want this process to run on. That is a string stored in class MyGlobals. Sorry if this is obvious or I'm using wrong terminology. I'm very inexperienced.

Comment: You start the process by giving calling this method with the path of your main zip file and the path of the directory you want to unzip it to. suppose the string in `MyGlobals.finalPathForWork` is the path of the target directory and `MyGlobals.ZipFilePath` is the path to the main zip file, you do `<ContainingType>.ExtractFile(MyGlobals.finalPathForWork, MyGlobals.ZipFilePath);` (be sure to replace `<ContainingType>` with the name of the type that contains this method).

Comment: Will it still work if all I can give it is the starting/main/root directory? I can give it the starting directory and the extract directory (which is just the starting directory + `"\Extracted"`) but don't have the `baseZipPath` because I don't know what zips are inside - only the starting directory: `MyGlobals.filePathForWork`. I want to run it on that folder. Or do I just pick a random zip somehow from that folder and send it that?

Comment: When I try to pass it the starting directory where all the zip files are stored, and the extracted directory (just the starting one + \Extracted) - I get an error on `Directory.EnumerateFiles(extractPath, "*.zip");`  saying: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Yeah, well, as for your first question - the answer is no. If you only provide the path to a directory, you need to adjust the code to search all the zip files in that directory. For your second question, that's a typo on the answer - `string[] nestedZipFiles` should be `var nestedZipFiles` - I've edited that in.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Here is the complete working & tested code. Before running, just change the zipPath and extractPath.

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string zipPath = @"C:\TestZipFiles\test.zip"; 
        string extractPath = @"C:\TestZipFiles\extractfiles";
        int dbFileCount = 0;
        ExtractRootFile(zipPath, extractPath, ref dbFileCount);
    }

    private static void DeleteSubFolderAndFiles(string destinationPath)
    {
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(destinationPath);
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            File.Delete(fileName);

        string[] subdirectoryEntries = 
        Directory.GetDirectories(destinationPath);
        foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
        {
            DeleteSubFolderAndFiles(subdirectory);
            if (Directory.GetFiles(subdirectory).Length == 0 && 
         Directory.GetDirectories(subdirectory).Length == 0)
            {
                Directory.Delete(subdirectory);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void ExtractRootFile(string baseZipPath, string extractPath, ref int dbFileCount)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(extractPath))
            DeleteSubFolderAndFiles(extractPath);

        if (!Directory.Exists(extractPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(extractPath);

        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(baseZipPath, extractPath);
        extractPath = extractPath + @"\test"; //replace this with dynamic value of first zip file only.
        RecursivelyExtractChildFolders(extractPath, ref dbFileCount);
    }
    public static void RecursivelyExtractChildFolders(string extractPath, ref int dbFileCount)
    {
        string[] nestedZipDirectories = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(extractPath, "*.zip");
        string[] nestedDBDirectories = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(extractPath, "*.db");
        if (nestedDBDirectories.Length > 0)
            dbFileCount = dbFileCount + nestedDBDirectories.Length;

        foreach (var nestedZipDirectory in nestedZipDirectories)
        {
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(nestedZipDirectory, extractPath);
        }

        if (Directory.Exists(extractPath))
        {
            string[] subdirectoryEntries = 
            Directory.GetDirectories(extractPath);
            foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
            {
                RecursivelyExtractChildFolders(subdirectory, ref dbFileCount);
            }
        }
    }
```